# Hide external html while angular app is loading

Tags: angular

In my `index.thml`i have a lot of stuff that are not related to my app, it is just static header and footer provided by other guys, a lot of markup + styles.

so the question is can I do not show it untill styles from `styles.css` is loaded?

I thinking about some loader, but i believe there is a better soultion.

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/9003363/7019742

Comment: Not even close, static html are appearing without styles, that's all, this is not a duplicate.

Comment: okay... flag retracted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you will make prod  build, your problem will be resolved.

```
ng build --prod
```

Thanks.

Comment: actually, it is.  checkd it before

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure exactly what you are trying to achieve, but what you can do is:

1. Add a *showLater* class and display:none inline for these elements that you don't want to see until later

   `<div class="showLater" style="display:none">Content to hide until styles are loaded</div>`
2. override in in style.css with !important

   .showLater {display: block !important;}